# paper_trail gem saving versions with object_changes nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, paper-trail-gem

We just started using the [PaperTrail gem](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail) and have noticed that 75% of the records in the versions table have nil for the `object_changes` column. Any idea why this would be happening and how we can stop it?

Using Rails 5.1 and PaperTrail 10.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nil object changes is due to touch events on attributes that were skipped. The only solution I came up with for that is to only track versions on create, update and destroy.

I also discovered that we had duplicate version records. We turned on PaperTrail for all models by putting the below in `ApplicationRecord`, this caused duplicate versions to be created if a class inherited from another one. ie If you have `class Foo < Bar` and do `Bar.create` that would create 2 identical version records.

Initial Version in `ApplicationRecord`

```
def self.inherited(subclass)
  super
  subclass.send(:has_paper_trail)
end
```

Final Version

```
def self.inherited(subclass)
  classes_to_skip = %w[Foo]
  attributes_to_skip = [:bar_at]
  on_actions = [:create, :update, :destroy]

  super
  unless classes_to_skip.include?(subclass.name)
    subclass.send(:has_paper_trail, on: on_actions, ignore: attributes_to_skip)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 10):

Building up on @Scott's answer, create an initializer and set PaperTrail's global config (version 10+ only) to ignore the `:touch` events.

This was creating millions of needless versions in our database.

*`config/initializers/paper_trail.rb`*

```rb
PaperTrail.config.has_paper_trail_defaults = {
  on: %i[create update destroy]
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer. It is easy to implement and works flawless.